# How to use mod_rewrite to ignore a second variable if empty

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to set up mod_write in my HTACCESS file to rewrite one of my URLs. I'm using $_GET to pass a tag name and an optional page number (for pagination) to a file called tags.php.

Here's the filename with varialbles: **tags.php?t=textname&s=#**

(In the URL above, # is the page number.)

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to write the URL as **domain.com/tags/textname/#/**, but I also want to allow **domain.com/tags/textname/** if the user lands on the first page (no pagination variable needed to be passed).

Here's my mod_rewrite code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tags\.php    [NC]
RewriteRule ^tags/(.*)/$ /tags.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tags/(.*)/(.*)/$ /tags.php?t=$1&s=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The code works perfectly when I visit **domain.com/tags/textname/**. Where it fails is when I try visiting **domain.com/tags/textname/1/**, because instead of mod_rewrite passing **tags.php?t=textname&s=1**, it passes **tags.php?t=textname/1&s=**

Anyone see anything I'm doing wrong with my first or second rewriterule to prevent the second rule from working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Flipping the RewriteRules worked by putting the more descriptive statement first. Updating for anyone else having this problem.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tags\.php    [NC]
RewriteRule ^tags/(.*)/(.*)/$ /tags.php?t=$1&s=$2 [QSA,NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^tags/(.*)/$ /tags.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
```